# Workflow Hates Certain Users

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a workflow that uses the Modified By column in a library to trigger changes. If a certain user has made a change, the workflow acts. I indicate which user in the workflow in Designer.

However, it appears to dislike certain users. (myself being one of them.) I thought perhaps it's a permission issue, but I can't get any clear resolution or find the root problem. Has anyone had this issue?​

Comment: Please be more specific, this too general and vague.

Comment: Agree with above, I'd suspect permissions as well, but would be more concerned about how workflow author, the SharePoint App Pool which governs the workflow and the given user interact on permissions too.